# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005) when connecting C#-Client to C++ Server

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, tcpclient

I want to initiate a TCP connection between my Android smartphone and my Win10 computer. I have a C++ server running that can be easily connected with other C++ clients. My C# client on Xamarin throws the following exception:

> {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Connection refused   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP)      [0x000b6] in :0 at
>   AndroidSocketClient.MainActivity.ConnectServer (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00039]

**C++ Server**

```cpp
#include<io.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(27015);

    //Bind
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*) & server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*) & client, &c);
    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    puts("Connection accepted");

    //Reply to client
    const char* message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
    send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);

    getchar();

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

**C#-Client**

```cs
public void ConnectServer(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[10];

    IPHostEntry iphostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAdress = iphostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 27015);

    Socket client = new Socket(ipAdress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        client.Connect(ipEndpoint);
        Console.WriteLine("Socket created to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        while (true)
        {
            string message = "Test";
            byte[] sendmsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            int n = client.Send(sendmsg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Transmission end.");
}
```

**Tested Solutions:**

I already tried turning off the firewall and permitted internet connection.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to yourself, not to your server.

Comment: Is the server running?  The exception you are getting will occur under two conditions 1) The Server is not running.or you do not have a route to the server.  Use Ping to check connection from cmd.exe.  try both IP of server and Computer Name. 2) There is another application already connected to the same server using the same port.  You can verify from cmd.exe using following to check TCP status : >Netstat -a

Comment: @GSerg Could you elaborate this for me?

Comment: The client program that you are running on your phone is trying to connect to a server on that same phone. You said the server is on a desktop Win10 computer. It is not trying to connect to that. What do you think `Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())` does?

Comment: Yikes! Changed Dns.GetHostName() to the computer name, now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!